# unable to get subscription details when logging in with service principal id in azure using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, subscription, azure-powershell, service-principal

I am trying to login in with service principal id using PowerShell. By doing this I want to connect with my Azure Data Factory and stop triggers. But at the initial phase of execution of code it gives an error. I paste a piece of code and results.

```
$resourceGroupName = 'my-resource-group'
$dataFactoryName = 'my-azure-data-factory-name'
$applicationid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx'
$secretKey = 'my-secret-key'
$tenantID = 'my-tenant-id'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretKey -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applicationid,$password)
$x= Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantID

#Gather a list of triggers to stop them
$allTriggers = Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Trigger -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -DataFactoryName $dataFactoryName
```

**Result:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you add your service principal to the `Access control (IAM)` of your ADF in the portal?

Comment: Do we need to check any specific role also?

Comment: There are many roles have the permission to run the command, just tell me what is the role of your service principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can reproduce your issue, this was caused by your service principal who did not have a role in your data factory/subscription.

[image]

To fix the issue, navigate to the ADF or subscription in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> add your service principal as a role, e.g. `Data Factory Contributor`/ `Contributor`. To add the role, your user account which logged in the portal needs to be the `Owner` role of your ADF/subscription.

[image]

After adding the role, run the command to login again, then it will work fine. (I test with the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0) module, for your `AzureRm` module, it is the same logic)

[image]

Comment: Wowww, your answer working like a charm... Thanks a lot for working on my issue dedicatedly and posted a detailed answer.